# How to animate multiple balls - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, matplotlib

I would like to animate multiple balls bouncing on the boundaries but not on each other. The height boundary should be moving at a constant speed determined by the user.

So I tried to first make a ball move in the boundaries I set for it.
This is the script:

```
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons
import numpy as np 
from time import sleep 
import numpy.random as rnd

def norme ( vecteur ): 
    return np.sqrt( np.dot(vecteur,vecteur) ) 



B = int(input( "How many balls: " ) )
N=1000
C=1
sx = 1000
sy = 200
Vmax = 50000
VY = 50000



class ball:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = rnd.randint(1,sx)
        self.y = rnd.randint(1,sy)
        self.vx = rnd.randint(1,Vmax)
        self.vy = rnd.randint(1,VY)

b = ball()
p, v, balls  = [], [], []
nv=np.sqrt(b.vx**2+b.vy**2)
dt = 100/ nv
for i in range(N): 

    b.x += b.vx * dt
    b.y += b.vy * dt
    if( b.x >= 1000 or b.x <=0 ):
        b.vx = - b.vx/C
    if( b.y >= 200 or b.y < 0 ):
        b.vy = -b.vy*C 
    p.append( (b.x,b.y) )
    v.append( (b.vx,b.vy) )

fig = plt.figure() 

mes_axes = plt.axes(xlim=(0, sx), ylim=(0, sy) ) 
mes_axes.set_title("Balle") 

TexteX = " Paroi amorphe si C = " + str(C) + " est < 1 " 
TexteY = " Paroi impulsive si 1/C = " + str(1./C) + " est > 1 "

plt.xlabel(TexteX) 
plt.ylabel(TexteY) 

balle, = mes_axes.plot( [], [],  marker = 'o', markersize = 15.0 ) 

def initialise(): 
    balle.set_data( [], [] ) 
    return balle,   

def AvanceBalle(n,mes_axes,fig): 
    x, y = p[n] 
    vx, vy  = v[n] 
    balle.set_data( p[n] )


    return balle, 

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,AvanceBalle,init_func=initialise,interval=100,frames=N, fargs=(mes_axes,fig), blit=True ) 


plt.show()
```

Then I tried to add to my loop

```
for i in range(N): 

    b.x += b.vx * dt
    b.y += b.vy * dt
    if( b.x >= 1000 or b.x <=0 ):
        b.vx = - b.vx/C
    if( b.y >= 200 or b.y < 0 ):
        b.vy = -b.vy*C 
    p.append( (b.x,b.y) )
    v.append( (b.vx,b.vy) )
```

a new loop to make multiple balls.
This is the new loop and it's not working

```
for i in range(B):
    b = ball()
    balls.append(b)


for i in range(B):
    x,y,vx,vy=balls[i].x,balls[i].y,balls[i].vx,balls[i].vy
    xax.append((x,y))
    yax.append((vx,vy))
    for i in range(N): 

        x += vx * dt
        y += vy * dt
        if( x >= 1000 or x <=0 ):
            vx = - vx/C
        if( y >= 200 or y < 0 ):
            vy = -vy*C 
        p.append( (x,y) )
        v.append( (vx,vy) )
```

The program keeps animating 1 ball and not the others.
P.S. I'm a beginner in python and most of the animating part, I took from a ready script that was handed to me by my professor.
Please note that some of these values are put so that I can change them later like: C=1

Comment: The update function `AvanceBalle` needs to set the data for 3 balls, not one. Similarly, `p` and `v` need to return the data for 3 balls, not one (at the moment, you seem to append the movement of your 3 balls to one 'p' and one 'v').

Comment: I get what you mean, but can you give me an idea on how to update the function     AvanceBalle . I have almost no idea how the function works because I took a ready one. If you can guide me it would help a lot.

Comment: I suggest you first carefully read the documentation for `FuncAnimation` found [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) to understand the code that you have so far. We are happy to help with technical problems but in this is stackoverflow not coding bootcamp 101 so we expect you to do your homework before you ask.